# Java, using Loop ask how many times something was repeated

Tags: java

```
string name;
string DOB;
int hours, status;
int countworkers = 0;
       for (int s = 0; s < number; s++)
  System.out.print("Enter the amount of worker: ");
       int number = sc.nextInt();


     System.out.print("name: ");
           name = sc.next();

           System.out.print("id number: ");
           id = sc.next();

           System.out.print("hours worked: ");
           hour = sc.nextInt();

           System.out.print("What is their Status: fulltimeHome, fulltimeonsite parttimehome, parttimeonsite");
           status = sc.next();
           switch (status) {
case "parttime":
    System.out.println("pay  " + 3465 ) ; 
    break;
case "fulltime":
    System.out.println("pay  " + (hours * 500) ) ; 
    break;
```

[NOTE: this isn't the full code, I removed the last two case] My code is using the for-loop.
How can I get my program to calculate in total the people that enter they are at home workers (fulltimeHome, parttime home) and those who are working on site (fulltimeonsite, parttimeonsite).

Comment: You may want to read [ask]. A [mcve] with proper indentation that actually compiles would help. Plus a better description on what the code does now and what you expect it to do instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have 2 variables onSite and homeWorkers for example and in the correct cases add 1 to the correct one.

```
int onSite = 0, homeWorkers = 0;
```

and

```
case "parttime":
    System.out.println("pay  " + 3465 ) ; 
    onSite ++;
    break;
case "fulltime":
    System.out.println("pay  " + (hours * 500) ) ; 
    onSite ++;
    break;
case "parttimeHome":
    System.out.println("pay  " + 3465 ) ; 
    homeWorkers ++;
    break;
case "fulltimeHome":
    System.out.println("pay  " + (hours * 500) ) ; 
    homeWorkers ++;
    break;
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering in the end, how would I get the program to tell me the total amount that are fulltime vs parttime.